# POD Struct Serialisation Using Type Punning

Tags: c++, serialization, struct, casting, type-punning

I wanted to figure out a way to serialise a POD struct into a vector of bytes. My application is to serialise some game state objects in my game so they can be saved to file, and at some point be retrieved again using the reverse process.

I'm using `#pragma pack(1)` to force alignment to 1 byte.

To do the serialisation, I'm simply casting the whole struct to `void*` then to `unsigned char*` and then using the resulting pointer to initialise the vector using `make_unique`.

I'm relatively new to c++, and I'm wondering if it is safe to do these kind of things. Here are a few of my burning questions:

1. Is the struct memory layout guaranteed?
2. Is the struct size guaranteed given that I'm forcing packing to the nearest byte?
3. How might I handle when more complex data is inside the struct, e.g. a vector or another struct? I guess I'd need to do some kind of recursive serialisation in that case.
4. Any neat preprocessor tricks that might help me flip the endianness with little effort?
5. Would it be safe to go in the opposite direction; deserialising by casting an `unsigned char[]` back to the struct type?

Code below is an example of what I'm talking about. Runs in [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/yoUxfZ).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

#pragma pack(1)
struct PODStruct {
    unsigned char a;
    unsigned int b;
    unsigned int c;

    std::unique_ptr<std::vector<unsigned char>> serialise() const;
};
#pragma pack()

std::unique_ptr<std::vector<unsigned char>> PODStruct::serialise() const {
    auto rawChar = (unsigned char*)((void*)this);
    auto serDataPtr = std::make_unique<std::vector<unsigned char>>(rawChar, rawChar + sizeof(PODStruct));
    return serDataPtr;
}

int main() {
    PODStruct foo = {0x38, 0x34353637, 0x30313233};

    auto bar = foo.serialise();

    for (auto byte : *bar) {
        std::cout << byte << std::endl; 
    }

    std::cout << "Size (bytes): " << bar->size() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would use something like boost serialization. This will work if used on the same machine. Padding and alignment can differ with different architectures/compilers/versions and make this break.

Comment: Same comment as on Reddit: why is your `serialize` not returning `std::vector<unsigned char>`?